# Absolute extreme values

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$D$ is a region (in the first quadrant) bounded by the lines $x=0$, $y=2$, and $y=2x$
$$f(x,y)=2x^2-4x+y^2-4y+1$$ 
find absolute extreme values of $f(x,y)$ over $D$ and also determine the points at which those extreme values occur.

I have drawn an area, but I am still a little unsure. Please help me.

Comment: Refer to [MathJax help here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Here you are given a function $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$, and you are asked to find the extrema of $f$ on a certain subset $D \subset \mathbb{R^2}$. The process is laregely similar to single variable calculus. To locate such extrema, you first have to locate all the critical points of $f$, which means set the derivative of $f$ equal to $0$; i.e set $Df(x,y) = 0$, and find what $(x,y)$ can be. In your case, this is equivalent to solving the following system of equations:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) &= 0 \\\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) &= 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Once you solve this system of equations,you should get a bunch of points $(x,y)$. Now, for each point $(x,y)$ which lies in the interior of $D$, you should evaluate $f(x,y)$ (you should get a single real number now).

(BTW, sometimes, it may happen that there are critical points of the function $f$, but the critical point may not lie inside the region $D$ which is of interest. If this happens, don't worry, you didn't do anything wrong, just analyze the boundary separately)

Next, you should analyze what happens on the boundary of $D$. For example, along the line $x=0$, you have

\begin{equation}
f(0,y) = y^2-4y + 1
\end{equation}
This is now just a function of a single variable $y$, so by the methods of single variable calculus, you should be able to locate the extrema of this function. Similarly, along the line $y=2x$, you get the function

\begin{equation}
f(x,2x) = 2x^2 - 4x + 4x^2 - 8x + 1 = \dots,
\end{equation}
which is a function of a single variable $x$; so once again you should be able to analyze this. Repeat the process for the last part of the boundary

**Recap:**
Analyze the interior and boundary of $D$ separately. In the interior, set $Df(x,y) = 0$ (or equivalently, set the partial derivatives to $0$). Then, analyze the boundary separately.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem in 2 ways.

**Using Calculus**

$\partial f(x,y)/ \partial x = 0 = 4x - 4$

therefore, $x = 1$.

Now, substitute $x = 1$ in $f(x, y)$

$\partial f(x,y)/ \partial y = 0 = 2y - 4$

therefore, $y = 2$. Now, $x = 1 , y = 2$ will give you the global minima which is also the absolute minima of $f(x, y)$ over $D$, since $(x,y) = (1, 2)$ lies on the boundary of the region $D$.

This minimum value is $f(1, 2) = -5$

**Using Completing the square method**

Write $f(x,y)=2x^2 − 4x + y^2 − 4y + 1$ as $f(x, y) = 2(x - 1)^2 + (y-2)^2 -5$

The minimum value for the above function occurs when $x - 1 = 0$ and $y - 2 = 0$

Hence, the result.

Comment: nice quick way of finding the minimum for this question, but I disagree with your last statement that there will be no other extrema; the region $D$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, so it attains a maximum value somewhere in $D$ (which is different from its minimum, since $f$ is not constant on $D$)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for letting me know. I have edited the post. Here is my doubt- x can take any positive value right? Then the maximum value of the function in the region D is infinity. Am I right?

Comment: no $x$ can only take the values allowed by the region $D$ (which is a comapct set). so the maximum value of $f$ on $D$ is some finite value